# How to write a Function<Flux<MyObject>, Flux<String>> with opencsv

Tags: project-reactor, opencsv

How do I write a Function that map's an object to a csv string?

```java
public Function<Flux<CleanAccessLogLine>, Flux<String>> toCsv() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the Flux.map function: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#map-java.util.function.Function-

```
public Function<Flux<CleanAccessLogLine>, Flux<String>> toCsv() {
  return input -> input.map(line -> toCsv(line));
}

String toCsv(CleanAccessLogLine line) {
  // logic that converts the CleanAccessLogLine into a CSV String
}
```